# jquery: How can I size element using .each()

Tags: jquery, each

Good Day.
I'm using table-less forms and want to size the `<label>` block-element. This I can do, like:
HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <form id="profile" blah...>
    <div id="fContainer">
      <div class="ffContainer">
        <label for='email'>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" blah...>
      </div>
      <div class="ffContainer">
        <label for='name'>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" blah...>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end fContainer -->
   </form>
</div><!-- end main-content -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ffContainer label").each(function(){
     if( $(this).width() > w) {
       w = $(this).width();
     };
  });
  // have widest label now make all of them the same size so that they fit
  $(".ffContainer label").attr("style","width:" + Math.round( $(window).width() / w) + "%;");

}); // end document.ready
```

This does the job just fine. All the `<label>` fields are the same width and my table-less form looks pretty.

However, if I want to add a second form on the page, I try to loop thru each set of forms, grab the widest width, and set the `<label>` to that width; then move on to the next form on the page and do the same.

Problem: I can't seem to get the second form's `<label>` width to be anything different from the first form's `<label>` width.

I tried this HTML:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <form id="profile" blah...>
    <div id="fContainer">
       <div class="ffContainer">
         <label for='email'>Email:</label>
         <input type="text" id="email" blah...>
       </div>
       <div class="ffContainer">
         <label for='name'>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="name" blah...>
       </div>
    </div><!-- end fContainer -->
  </form>

  <form id="delta" blah...>
    <div id="fContainer">
      <div class="ffContainer">
        <label for="car">Car:</label>
        <input type="text" id="car" blah...>
      </div>
      <div class="ffContainer">
        <label for='engine'>Engine:</label>
        <input type="text" id="engine" blah...>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
 </div><!-- end main-content -->
```

And here's the jQuery that isn't doing the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main-content #fContainer").each(function(){  // loop thru both #fContainer blocks
    $(".ffContainer label").each(function(){       // loop thru all label elements
       if( $(this).width() > w){
         w = $(this).width();
       };                                          // have widest label as var w
       $(".ffContainer label").each(function(){    // loop thru all labels again to indivdually set each attr
          $(this).attr("style","width:" + Math.round($(window).width() / w) + "%;");
       });
     }); // end .ffContainer label loop MOVE ON TO NEXT FORM GROUP
  }); // end #fContainer loop
 }); // end document.ready
```

Any help would be great!
There might be a typo above, but I'm certain there's not in my code.
I really don't want to name the second form divs something else and repeat all the jQuery code, but don't have a problem naming the second divs something else if I don't have to repeat all the jQuery code (hope I'm making sense there).

Thanks.

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have two elements with the same `id`. In your second example, there's two elements with an `id` of `fContainer`.

Comment: ok, but then how would you suggest to dynamically go thru each `<form>` set of `<label>` without having to copy all the jQuery code and manually changing the selector?

Comment: Perhaps use a class named `fContainer`, rather than using IDs; multiple elements can have the same class.

Comment: that's what I changed so that I could keep the positioning of that `<div>`, but still no luck...all `<label>` in both forms have the same width, when each form should have it's own label width.

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect the code you're now using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your HTML (remove the duplicate IDs), then try

```
$('form').each(........)
```

instead of

```
$("#main-content #fContainer").each(........)
```

Change

```
$(".ffContainer label").each(...)
```

into

```
$(".ffContainer label", this).each(...)
```

so the jQuery selector is within the scope of one form at a time.

Also, it might be a good idea to have `var w = 0;` before `$(".ffContainer label", this).each(...)` to ensure that the value of `w` doesn't leak from one run to the next.

**UPDATE**: I went ahead and plugged your code into a test page. There was a nesting issue that was hard to see from the question. I cleaned it up a bit and the code below appears to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").each(function(){  // loop thru both #fContainer blocks
    var w = 0;
    $(".ffContainer label", this).each(function(){       // loop thru all label elements
      if( $(this).width() > w){
        w = $(this).width();
      }
    });

    var percent_width = (Math.round(w / $(window).width() * 100)) + "%"; // This calc only needs to be performed once per form.
    $(".ffContainer label", this).each(function(){    // loop thru all labels again to indivdually set each attr
      $(this).width(percent_width);
    });
  }); // end #fContainer loop
}); // end document.ready
```

**UPDATE**: For details about jQuery selector context
Check out [this blog post](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery) referenced in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553766/jquery-selector-context-question)

Comment: ok, changed #fContainer to .fContainer so that I could keep the positioning, and it get's rid of the duplicate IDs. Added the `, this)' to each .each(), and `w=0;` but no avail.

Comment: Thanks for trying that. Only made a small tweak as it seems as if it wasn't quite making the label width the correct size -- I multiplied the `percent_width * 2` and that is just fine.

Comment: So the key to solving this was the addition of the `, this` in the two sub `.each()` functions. Can you point to a resource on this so that I can explore it more in-depth? Again, thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with some links to more info. Glad I could help.